# Adding Table to Magento 1.8.0.1 Short Description Adds tons of Line Breaks

Tags: magento-1.8, product

This problem is kind of odd for me. Usually errors such as this are easily corrected, but this one is new for me.

My Sub description is simply....

```
    <p>This Kit Includes.</p>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Drawstring Carrying Case</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>DeniClean Pipe Cleaning Solution</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Joufiah Oil Polishing Solution</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Iron Reaming Rod</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Stiff Bristle Cleaning Brush</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Microfiber Cleaning Cloth</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

However, on the front end, my code ends up displaying like this.

```
    <div class="short-description">
                <div class="std"><p>This Kit Includes.</p><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>   
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Drawstring Carrying Case</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>DeniClean Pipe Cleaning Solution</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Joufiah Oil Polishing Solution</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Iron Reaming Rod</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Stiff Bristle Cleaning Brush</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1x</td>
    <td>Microfiber Cleaning Cloth</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table><br>
    </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, there are 27 line breaks randomly added to the code on the front end. And I cannot figure out what would cause these lines to be inserted in to the code.

I wonder if anyone has any ideas to this, or if anyone could suggest what information I should supply to make the root of this problem easier to find. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a php nl2br someplace that is likely changing those new lines to breaks however I'm not sure why they are all being stacked in the front.  You could try removing the nl2br and see if that makes a difference in *template/catalog/product/view.phtml* or remove the new lines from your description.

Before (line 84)

```
<div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
```

After:

```
<div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?></div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. There was no way to remove those breaks by removing them from the description as they are ONLY added on the front end view. The breaks do not show up on the backend. However this line of code fixed it. Could you tell me what PHP nl2br does? Why its needed or if it is needed at all?